# Apartment requires that I consent to them using images of myself on social media

Tags: contract-law

I am signing a contract for an apartment.  In it, there is a section stating that I agree to the apartment using images, video, and/or audio clips of me wherever they'd like (Facebook, their website, etc.)  I'm not comfortable with this, but I want to live here.  Can they really make me do this?

Comment: Generally, people are free to contract to whatever they can agree on; so if you don't agree, then try to negotiate with them to drop it, or don't live there.  Some jurisdictions do have laws saying that various terms in a residential lease are not valid or enforceable - but you'll have to tell us what jurisdiction you are in (maybe down to the city since much of this is locally regulated).

Comment: @NateEldredge this is an answer, don’t post it as a comment

Comment: It's a request for the question to be clarified.

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: I'd look at that wording pretty closely. Does it allow bugs about the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sue them for commercially exploiting your image without permission, so the waiver is necessary. It is entirely legal to require of tenants (even if weird) that they be part of an advertising campaign, in a specified way: it's also your right to refuse to sign. There is a minuscule chance that there is a local ordinance prohibiting such a clause.

Answer (score 1):

They can ask for you to appear on social media for them, and you can refuse.

Contracts are negotiable, you can simply cross that section out before signing if you want to. It's then up to them if they accept it or not.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you have modified the contract in any way, you are most likely sacrificing any future argument of "no meeting of the minds" from prevailing, as can sometimes occur with an unaltered form contract.